# How to make Rmarkdown carry over sections of code?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I have a piece of RMarkdown code that runs fine in one block.

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
data("PlantGrowth")
set.seed(1234)
PlantGrowth %>% sample_n_by(group, size = 1)
levels(PlantGrowth$group)
```
````

However, if I try to break it into pieces of code, which I need to do in order to add explanations, I get the following error in the RMarkdown console.

````
```{r eval=TRUE}
library(tidyverse)
data("PlantGrowth")
set.seed(1234)
```
Comment the code here

```{r eval=TRUE}
PlantGrowth %>% sample_n_by(group, size = 1)
levels(PlantGrowth$group)
```
Say more stuff...

Error in PlantGrowth %>% sample_n_by(group, size = 1) : could not find function "%>%" Calls: <Anonymous> ...withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval Execution Halted.
````

Is there a way to make markdown carry over the libraries and variables loaded in previous code blocks up to the end of the document?

Comment: You added the chunk option `eval=FALSE` which means that the chunk is not evaluated, i.e. `library(tidyverse)` is not evaluated and the package is not loaded.

Comment: @stefan The results is the same even if I use `eval=TRUE`. I will edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I just ran your code chunk with `eval=TRUE` in a fresh Rmd and it works fine after adding the missing `library(rstatix)` needed for `sample_n_by`.

Comment: @stefan I added rstatix and it still doesn't run. Strangely, it runs fine on another computer.

Comment: Hm. Try with restarting your R session. If that does not help try with adding just the fixed chunk in a fresh and clean Rmd and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you insatlled `tidyverse` and `rstatix` in your env.

````
```{r eval=TRUE}
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
data("PlantGrowth")
set.seed(1234)
```
Comment the code here

```{r eval=TRUE}
PlantGrowth %>% sample_n_by(group, size = 1)
levels(PlantGrowth$group)
```
````

[image]

Comment: I updated knitr and now it works.